# Symfony2 Relation two entity, arraycollection

Tags: symfony, entity-relationship, arraycollection

I have created 2 entities
`User` and `Photo`

Now I want to create one-to-many relation.
Suppose I have this code in the `User` entity class:

```php
// User.php
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $photos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

when i add the photo's form into user's form, similarly to how it's done in this code

```php
// UserType.php
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...
        $builder->add('photos', new PhotoType());
    }
```

it throws:

```
Expected argument of type "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Photo", "Doctrine
\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given
```

so how can I add photo's form into user's form?

ps sorry for my english

Comment: molecule i not uderstand  ? what u want say me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaken in your form builder : you need a collection of PhotoType:

`$builder->add('photos', 'collection', array('type' => new PhotoType()));`

Comment: What is the equivalient of "type" for symony 3?